# or в цикле while

Tags: python, python-3.x

Подскажите в чем проблема не правильно работает цикл:

```
def humanMove(board, acessMove , mark):
    move = int(input('Введите число от 1 до %s '  %len(board)))
    if move in board:
        board[move-1] = mark
    else:
        print('Такого числа нет введите повторно ')
        while  (move != 1111) or (len(acessMove) != 8) :
            move = int(input('Введите число от 1 до %s '  %len(board)))
            print('Если хотите выйте наберите 1111')
```

Comment: Похоже, что нужно использоват `and` вместо `or`

Comment: Как замечено в ответе к вашему вопросу, в коде содержится сразу несколько ошибок. Опишите, пожалуйста, подробнее, какое поведение вы ожидаете от функции.

Comment: похожий вопрос: [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23294658/4279)

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Если я правильно понимаю желаемую логику работы, то у вас `while` должен быть снаружи, а `if` - внутри, как-то так:

```
def humanMove(board, acessMove , mark):
    while  (move != 1111) or (len(acessMove) != 8) :
            move = int(input('Введите число от 1 до %s '  %len(board)))
            print('Если хотите выйти, наберите 1111')
            if move in board: #здесь надо заменить на корректное условие
                board[move-1] = mark
                break
            else:
                print('Такого числа нет, введите повторно ')
```

Но есть еще ошибка в этом условии:

```
if move in board:
```

1. Если `board` - это массив, то метод `in` в условии:

   ```
   if move in board:
   ```

   будет проверять элементы, которые находятся в массиве (в вашем случае - список пометок), а не индексы этих элементов, и сравнивать их с значением, записанным в переменную move. Тогда следующее за этим присваивание `board[move-1]` выглядит бессмысленным, хотя с точки зрения попадания индекса в нужный диапазон оно корректно.

   Корректное условие может быть, например, таким:

   ```
   if move > 0 and move < len(board):
   ```

   или, как подсказывает следующая за ним строка в вашем коде, таким:

   ```
   if move > 0 and move < len(board) and board[move-1] != mark:
   ```

   добавленное условие проверяет, что выбранная позиция на доске уже не была ранее отмечена меткой mark.
2. Если `board` - словарь с числовыми ключами, то условие будет вызываться  корректно, но будет возвращать `KeyError` в некоторых случаях на следующей строке:

   ```
   board[move-1] = mark
   ```

   потому что при вызове `board[move-1]` вместо `board[move]` для каких-то значений `move` окажется так, что словарь `board` не содержит `move-1`.

Comment: Перед циклом неплохо бы инициализировать `move`. Если `board` - словарь то `board[move-1] = mark` прекрасно сработает для любого значения move, нужный ключ просто добавится

Answer (score 0):

Будем считать, что `board` является словарем с числовыми ключами, иначе в коде не просматривается смысл, как верно заметили выше.
Правильно ли я понимаю, что если первое введенное значение уже есть в `board`, то в цикл входить не надо?
Если так, то непонятно условие выхода из цикла, потому, что `accessMove` в приведенном коде не изменяется.

Т.е. если `len(accessMove) != 8`, то из цикла мы не выйдем никогда.

Если учесть, что Вы просите ввести число от 1 до len(board), похоже, что board все же массив, тогда вместо

```
move in board
```

нужно писать

```
move > 0 and move <= len(board)
```

Неясности условия выхода из цикла это не меняет.